# How to get the first and the last matching occurrence of an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

There is a interview question from AirBNB:

> You have a sorted array, and you want get the first index and the last index of the matching occurrence of an element by a function in python. If there is no match, return [-1.-1]. If there is a match, return [first_index,last_index].

This is my newbie solution, can anyone come up with a better one?

By the way, this question is from TechLead DailyInterviewPro.

```
def solution(array,key):
    start_index = -1
    ending_index = -1
    if key not in array:
        return [start_index,ending_index]
    else:
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if array[i]==key:
                if start_index == -1:
                
                    start_index = i
                    ending_index = i
                else:
                    ending_index = i
                    
        return [start_index,ending_index]
```

Comment: if you are preparing for coding then i suggest go for `Leetcode`

Comment: @khelwood: `list` doesn't have `rindex`; `str` provides `index` and `rindex` (as well as the similar `find` and `rfind`), but `list` only provides `index`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, an optimized solution that:

1. Uses `index` to push the work of confirming at least one value exists, and retrieving its index, to the C layer
2. Avoids scanning a single element more than needed, and doesn't make any copies (it doesn't access elements between the `start_index` and `end_index` at all):

```
def solution(array,key):
    try:
        return [array.index(key),
                len(array) - next(i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(array), 1) if x == key)]
    except ValueError:
        return [-1, -1]
```

It relies on `array.index` either computing the first element's index or raising `ValueError` (in which case no such element exists), then follows up by retrieving a single value from a genexpr running over the `list` in reverse order to get the index (the genexpr is guaranteed to find something, at worst it runs until it finds the same element the `index` call found). Technically, this does mean that if the element occurs only once, we test it for equality twice (coming from either end), but avoiding said "cost", while possible via `itertools.islice`, it hardly worth the bother.

If you really love one-liners, you could always do:

```
def solution(array,key):
    return [next((i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == key), -1)
            next((len(array) - i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(array), 1) if x == key), -1)]
```

though that solution does involve scanning the whole of `array` twice (once forward, once backward) when the element is not found (if the element exists though, the minimal number of elements are scanned).

Comment: I think that's the reason why try except is more useful in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

with one liner, using `list.index` function you can use

`[-1, -1] if key not in array else [arrary.index(key),len(array)-array[::-1].index(key)-1 ]`

little efficient code, if memory is not a concern, else need to use two pointer apprach

```
def solution(array, key):
    store_index = {}
    for index, value in enumarate(array):
         if value not in store_index:
              store_index[value] = []
         store_index[value].append(index)

    if key not in store_index:
       return [-1, -1]
    return [store_index[key][0], store_index[key][-1]]
```

Comment: Woo, that's really concise!

Comment: @Boyce Yes but not efficient, requiring to read the array up to 3 times, that should certainly matter during an interview. I guess recruiters will care more about efficient readable code than a hacky one liner ;)

Comment: yeah it is just one liner not efficient, add a solution

Comment: So, compared to the one liner, this approach creact a local dict in the function. And store the key(array to search through) as the key of it, and store all of its index, which only go through the array once. That's very inspiring!